# How can I choose my own build file in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, build, haxe

It`s my first steps in Haxe)

I need to build task with my own build task in VS code. I know that I can choose build task to run by using Shift+Ctrl+B, but no drop down list opens... And when I did find the list, my assembly file was not there...

Comment: Did you install the Haxe vscode extension? It can detect Haxe tasks automatically.

Comment: yeah...) I installed the haxe extension, but after that I connected to another server and forgot to install the extension there.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define a task in `tasks.json` then `Shift+Ctrl+B` will not show you anything.

If you have different configuration files you can use [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file) and the command `extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile` to create a QuickPick list of files to choose from and use it as an argument to Haxe